# How can I make my data frame workable for rowMeans (error codes: 'x' is not numeric and 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double')

Tags: r, error-handling, row, mean

I am just starting on my project and just trying to apply the simple rowMeans function but I came upon a chain of errors that I can't solve on my own.

I would start out like this:

```
FOBs$mean_pers <- rowMeans(FOBs[ ,c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29)])
```

This leads to the error code:

> Error in rowMeans(FOBs[, c(1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29)]) :
> 'x' must be numeric

So, I try to make my x numeric by using the as.numeric function:

```
FOBs$mean_pers <- rowMeans(as.numeric(FOBs[ ,c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29)]))
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

So, I try to unlist my data.

```
FOBs$mean_pers <- rowMeans(as.numeric(unlist(FOBs[ ,c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29)])))
```

> 'x' must be an array with at least two dimensions

If I understand right, this means that my dataset must have at least two columns and I totally get that if you unlist it it becomes just a bunch of unorganized data. But I have no other idea on how I could approach this problem. Did anyone have this problem before? Where could I have made a mistake?

My suspicion is that there is something wrong with my data (like the wrong format) but I am no R expert and to me, it all looks normal.

Thank you for your help!

Best, Tabea

Comment: We can't help without an actual sample of the FOBs object. Please share `FOBs[1:5, c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29)])`. You can use `dput`, as in `dput(FOBs[1:5 ,c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29)]))`

Comment: Anyway: `rowMeans` works with numeric matrices or numeric-only dataframes. FOBs is likely a list, which is not the same. Torturing the list into numeric is very likely not the way to go. In the `as.numeric(unlist(x))` attempt, you transform the whole list into a long numeric vector and loose all original dimensions (rows and columns), it is a useless vector

Comment: You need to convert the **columns** of the data frame to numeric, not the data frame itself. If you think all those columns should be numbers, run `FOBs[c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29)] = lapply(FOBs[c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29)], as.numeric)`. Then the `rowMeans` should work on those columns.

Comment: (Do note, there's probably a reason some of those columns aren't numeric - if you they have % signs or commas or other stuff, that might mess up the conversion. Using `readr::parse_number` instead of `as.numeric` might work better in cases like that.)

Comment: Beware that `readr:parse_number` doesn't know your data structure and will silently convert things that should never be converted together without warning or error. E.g. `parse_number(c("0.23","23%", "1 result: 23%"))` gives `0.23`, `23.00` and `1.00` which may well be misleading.